# how to get share count from stocktwits

Tags: stocktwits, socialshare

I like to integrate stocktwits url share in my site and I just want to know how to get share count of a particular URL like fb and twitter doing.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you mean how many clicks a particular link has received within the StockTwits stream or how many times the same link has been shared in the StockTwits stream?

Comment: I need how many times the same link has been shared in the stocktwits.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry we don't have that data available in the API. I will make note of it and maybe we offer such an endpoint in the future.

Comment: Thank you so much. If it comes in the near future then it will be very helpful.